# WPF is running well on development machine, but cannot run on other machines

Tags: wpf, deployment, sharpdevelop

I've got a problem with an wpf application.

I programming a wpf application with sharpdevelop 4.1.8000, it complied successful and is running well on the development machine.

When I copy the files from bin\debug to other machines (include the third part dll I used in project), the tool can't startup. I got a exception, the exception component is System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse. I don't know why this happened.

So I need your help. By the way, the development machine is win7 x64 enterprise, the version of .net framework is 4.0. The deployment machine were win7 x64, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your xaml namespaces, did you reference something that is in the GAC of your develop machine but bot present on the other client. Happened to me using a behaviour from System.Windows.Interactivity, worked on my dev machine because i had Blend installed but which wasn´t the case on the client.

Comment: I got the issue. This is because I used SQLite in my application. The x86 SQLite.NET dll can't run x64 system. Thanks for your answer.